# Using fnmatch to locate all folders with name pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a sequence of folders with the naming patter:
%y-%m-%d 
And I want to use fnmatch to find them and append them to a list. 
I am currently using this code:

```
    for root, subs, files in os.walk('.'):
      for name in subs:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, '%y-%m-%d'):
                folderlist.append(os.path.join(root, name))
```

But this results in an empty folderlist. I know the reason for this (%y-%m-%d is not a proper pattern as understood by fnmatch, but I dont know how to get around it.

Comment: what do the names of the directories you want to find look like

Comment: 2015-07-02
2015-07-03 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex:

```
reobj = re.compile('\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}')
for root, subs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for name in subs:
        if reobj.match(name):
            print(name)
```

Comment: No worries, if there was a possibility there could be other dirs that are not valid dates but still in the format 4_digits-2_digits-2_digits you could try to parse the date using datetime.strptime, if not then the regex will work fine

Comment: I dont think that will be a problem, however I will keep that in mind. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think `re` would be better instead of `fnmatch`, but here it is:

```
import os
from fnmatch import fnmatch

folderlist = []
for root, subs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for name in subs:
        if fnmatch(name, '[12][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789]-[01][0123456789]-[0123][0123456789]'):
            folderlist.append(os.path.join(root, name))

print(folderlist)
```

Comment: You are right about re being better, I just learned about its existence :) But thank you for the answer nevertheless, it works very well

Comment: You could use `regex = fnmatch.translate( '[12][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789]-[01][0123456789]-[0123][0123456789]');reobj = re.compile(regex)` then `if reobj.match(name)`